# Chrome: Can you print out a stack trace that's minimized?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm trying to troubleshoot an issue so I'm doing `console.trace` a lot.  In chrome, there's a way to hit the arrow button and collapse the stack trace to a single line.  What I'm wondering is, is there a way to print them in a collapsed state so I don't have to click the arrow by hand?

Comment: @raina77ow well I want to expand the stack trace in a lot of situations.

Comment: @raina77ow oh, then isn't that an answer to the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For some reasons it was decided that `console.trace()` should always start expanded. There's an [open issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=677929) in Chromium bugtracker about it, but it seems to be stalemated.

Meanwhile, you can just use `console.error()` instead: it starts collapsed, but can be expanded.